# get tweets from keyword

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

Is there any way to get tweets containing a keyword in java? I want to download as many as possible, I have seen a java library twitter4j but it gives only small number of tweets.

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentation of twitter api 
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search
Its rate limited though. I dont think there is a way around it. 
The rate limiting varies with open search apis and the ones that require authentication.
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=blue%20angels&rpp=5&include_entities=true&result_type=mixed
(Note - this link is copied from twiter api webpage)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the page size and number using Twitter4J to request more tweets.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws TwitterException {
    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();

    for (int page = 1; page <= 10; page++) {
        System.out.println("\nPage: " + page);
        Query query = new Query("#MyWorstFear"); // trending right now
        query.setRpp(100);
        query.setPage(page);
        QueryResult qr = twitter.search(query);
        List<Tweet> qrTweets = qr.getTweets();

        if(qrTweets.size() == 0) break;

        for(Tweet t : qrTweets) {
            System.out.println(t.getId() + " - " + t.getCreatedAt() + ": " + t.getText());
        }
    }
}
```